# Is a capacitor a high-pass filter or a band-pass filter?

Tags: capacitor, filter

This has been bugging me for a while now... Does a single capacitor, on its own, behave as a high-pass filter or a band-pass filter?

In a crystal radio set, you use a single capacitor as the tuning element, to select which radio frequency the radio will receive. This strongly implies that a capacitor is a band-pass filter.

But reading Wikipedia, it is suggested that a capacitor is actually a 1-pole high-pass filter.

Well, obviously it can't be both. So which is it?

(Bonus points for anybody who can point to an actual frequency response curve.)

Comment: I think in crystal radio sets you tune the capacitor of an LC tank, the capacitor is not the only element.

Comment: It'd be a low pass if you coupled your signal to ground with the capacitor; it'd be a high pass if the capacitor was in series with the signal. So I guess with a combination of the two I'd imagine you'd be able to make a band-pass filter.

Comment: An ideal capacitor with one lead as the input and the other as the output is a high pass filter since its impedance is \$Z_C = 1/(j\omega C)\$. At \$\omega = 0\$ the impedance is \$\infty\$ (i.e. open circuit = gain of 0). As \$\omega \to \infty\$ the impedance goes to 0 (i.e. short circuit = gain of 1).  But real capacitors do not have this ideal frequency response because of [parasitics](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/3887/51760).

Comment: A capacitor is an electronic components that can store energy and is ideally modeled by the differential equation \$I=C\dot{V}\$. A circuit that includes only a capacitor might do loads of different things, but since you are not providing a circuit I don't see how we can help you.

Comment: On its own a capacitor does nothing. As part of a circuit (i.e., with other components) it can be part of a low-pass filter, a high-pass filter, a notch filter, a bandpass filter, or whatever, depending on the rest of the circuit.

Comment: It seems @Samuel has made the critical observation...

Comment: While relevant only to substantially different questions which might share your title, the inductance if a *practical* capacitor gives it a self resonant frequency.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

A capacitor by itself is not a filter at all, neither high pass, low pass, nor anything else.

A capacitor can be used as *part* of a high pass, low pass, or band pass filter, depending on how it's connected to *other parts*.  For example, a capacitor with a resistor can be a high pass filter:

[image]

or a low pass filter:

[image]

Together with a inductor and some additional impedance (represented by the resistor), it can be a band pass filter:

[image]

Or a band rejection filter:

[image]

A crystal radio works like the left band pass filter.  C1 and L1 form a resonant tank that has high impedance at the resonant frequency and low impedance at other frequencies.  Even that by itelf is not a filter, since just a changing impedance isn't a filter.  It is the changing impedance working against some other impedance that forms a voltage divider that then makes a filter.  In the example above, R1 is that other impedance.  In a crystal radio, it is the impedance of the signal coupled to L1 magnetically by the antenna coil.  In that case the antenna coil is the primary of a transformer, and L1 is the secondary, which resonates at a particular frequency depending on the value C1 is tuned to.

### Added about crystal radio:

I see from the comments that there is some confusion about how the capacitor in a crystal radio works and how such a radio is tuned.  There are different ways a crystal radio can be made, but I'll stick to the very common configuration you can find all over the web, and that is implemented by most crystal radio kits:

[image]

The inductor is a single coil, ususally magnet wire wound round something like a carboard toilet paper roll.  The coil is essentially a transformer.  The transformer primary is the left section between the antenna and the tap.  Since the tap is grounded, there is no direct flow of current between the two sections of the coil.  Voltage is induced in the right part of the coil by transformer action.  The *only* way for the signal to get from the left part of the coil (the transformer primary) to the right part (the transformer secondary), is by the magnetic coupling between the two parts of the coil.

The transformer creates a higher voltage at its right end, although at a higher impedance.  Typical antennas have impedance in the 50-300 Ω range, whereas the crystal radio is intended to drive old style headphones that have a few kΩ impedance.  The higher voltage at a higher impedance is a better match to the headphones, and allows the very limited power from the antenna to be used more efficiently.

The inductance of the coil together with the capacitance form a high Q tank circuit.  The radio picks up a station when the capacitor is adjusted so that the tank resonates at the station's carrier frequency.  Due to the finite impedance of the antenna driving the tank as seen thru the transformer, and the impedance of the headphones loading the output, the capacitor and the coil together form a narrow band pass filter.

Comment: I clicked on this as the answer, but I wanted to add the following link, as something that the asker might want to look at to help understand passive analog circuits: http://www.falstad.com/circuit/

Comment: In summary, then, it is the *combination* of a capacitor and an inductor that makes it band-pass rather than just high-pass. This answers my literal question - yet at the same time, it seems that there is something drastically wrong with my understanding of this stuff. I will try to pinpoint where I'm going wrong, and ask a separate question...

Comment: In the example you gave, there's little or no mutual inductive coupling between the [long-wire] antenna and the tank coil, so  any transformer action between the antenna and the tank coil will be trivial.  In reality, depending on the length of the antenna and the wavelength of the RF it intercepts, it'll look like a voltage source series-connected to the tank through an  impedance which is either resistive, capacitive, or inductive.

Comment: @EMFi: I rolled back your edit for reasons we discussed before.  I did then fix the typo in "resistor", but "band rejection filter" makes more sense than "band reject filter".  As for the crystal radio, The typical version has a coil wrapped around a paper tube with a tap near one end.  The antenna is connected to the end near the tap, and the tap to ground.  The resonant coil is from the tap to the other end.  The *only* way for RF to get to the resonant coil is by transformer coupling between the two parts of the coil.

Comment: As for "The _only_ way for RF to get to the resonant coil is by transformer coupling between the two parts of the coil.", I'd like for you to explain how RF _won't_ get to the tank if the coil isn't tapped and the antenna is connected directly to the ungrounded end of the tank.

Comment: Is it relevant to add that a certain (high) frequency, even a high-pass configuration will start to attenuate the signal (effectively acting as a bandpass)? Like a small introduction to the frequency response of a circuit... Or maybe the nuance would be confusing for a somewhat less advanced user...

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Maybe keep in mind that the resistors in these filters could also be the input or output impedances of the load or the source. For example, a decoupling capacitor across the power supply rails is a low-pass filter, with R1 being some small value provided by the resistance of the wire, etc. This may explain why sometimes you hear things discussed as "filters", even though the only intentional component is a capacitor.

Comment: @EMFi: You misunderstand the crystal radio circuit I was referring to.  You are somehow thinking of a single-coil type.  I mentioned "antenna coil" and "tap", but since that apparently was still unclear, I have added the schematic of the type of crystal radio I was referring to.  I hope this clears up any confusion.

Comment: One picture is worth a thousand words...

Comment: @Doombot: I deliberately stayed away from such issues. The OP has enough confusion just understanding how ideal capacitors work that I felt this isn't the time to introduce the non-ideal characteristics of real components. I'm agreeing with you that these effects are real, but that they are too advanced a topic for this question.

Answer (score 8):

A capacitor alone is not usually a filter at all.

It can form either a high-pass or low-pass filter, in conjunction with a resistor, or it can form either of those or a bandpass filter, in conjunction with an inductor.

In the crystal set, if your schematic you are looking at is old enough, there may be no inductor visible, and no good explanation why the capacitor works as a tuning element.

Here, the missing fact is that the antenna itself was acting as the inductor, and the explanations may not make that clear because it may not have been well understood by the writers before sometime around the mid 1920s.